# ASP.NET Webforms Using Session In Different Threads

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I am trying to run 5 tasks in parallel using Parallel.Foreach() but the problem is that username that will be used to connect to database is stored in Sessions for some reason and when I try to run any query in Task.Run() or Parallal.Foreach() I get null sessions.

I am unable to understand how to properly use await/async to achieve this task.

## Action: Start Job Scheduler behind web button click:

```
 // In same webform page inside constructer 
 // I am setting all the session variables which are used to connect to database.
 // Calling Process method
 new SimpleJobScheduler.SimpleJobScheduler().Process();
```

## Process method:

```
  // GetJobsFromTable() runs fine and I am getting jobs to execute
  var dt = GetJobsFromTable();

    Parallel.For(0, dt.Rows.Count, i => {

         var item = dt.Rows[i];

         ProcessJob(item);

   });
```

ProcessJob method performs the job but further runs a query against table Jobs. But I get null sessions and hence query is not executed.

Comment: Have you considered passing in the variables as parameters.....?

Comment: @Stefan what variables?

Comment: *"username that will be used to connect to database is stored in Sessions"* ... and; *"I am setting all the session variables which are used to connect to database."*

Comment: @Stefan actually there are more than 1 variables to pass and in future they may increase as well. Also I have already designed a simple class that has CRUD functions implemented, I am basically passing query in it, can't pass those variables.

Comment: I seriously doubt that this is a good design. I also argue the "simplicity" of such a class if it requires a Session dictionary.

Comment: @Stefan I 100% agree. This session system is not designed by me and I already hate it. It should be a static class that can be accessible everywhere. But I have to use Sessions since its implemented on whole project.

Comment: Okay, the problem in your case is that the Session Dictionary is probably resolved using `HttpContext.Current.Session`; when launching another thread, `HttpContext.Current` most likely is `null`. Can you verify if this is the way that it's being resolved? Or is it being set in another way? I am asking because you have a couple of options. 1) adjust the lib and add the mentioned parameters. 2) recreate the Session dictionary, 3) pass in a dictionary object 4) use evel reflection to set an internal dictionary.... but we need more info for that.

Comment: And: do you get any errors/exceptions while executing your code?

Comment: @Stefan Yes HttpContext.Current is null so can't access that, I get exception for that.

Comment: Okay, then, also; please include the code where you are setting the new httpcontext, and the session state variables.